# Laravel share model and relationship to child

Tags: laravel

I have 3 model ( media, comic, movie ), media is base model and the others is child ( comic, movie ). media model have own table ( medias ) that consists of id, title, synopsis.

i used to access media model in MediaController

```
Media::all();
```

media model function

```
genre()
language()
actor()
```

How to media model can share all things include function relationship. let's say

```
$medias = Media::all();

return $medias->genre;
```

to comic and movie model.

```
$comics = Comic::all();

return $comics->genre;
```

so i don't create each relationship function each model, so far i can access table inside media model by set table as medias table inside child model.

```
// comic, movie model
protected $table = 'medias';

// comic controller
$comics = Comic:all();
return $comics;

// $comics->genre ERROR
```

But i can't access all media function relationship like genre, actor, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about Traits. It allows to you attach to any model and it would automatically extends whatever function you have inside the Trait class. For example:

```
<?php

namespace App;

trait HasAccountTrait
{
    public function account()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Account::class);
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    use HasAccountTrait;
    
    ...
}
```